# How to develop a new pkg version while using the old one

Tags: python, setuptools

I am developing my own pkg with `console_scripts` in python.
I installed a stable version:

```
python setup.py install
```

I already use this version. I want to implement and test some improvements.
How can i do something like the following without "loosing" my installed version:

```
python setup.py develop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to use different [virtualenvs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/): one for your current release, one for your development.

For the current release:

```
cd /path/to/virtualenv/dir/
virtualenv my_app
source my_app/bin/activate
pip install my_app  # or a path to my last wheel
```

Instead of using `pip`, you can run `python setup.py install`, that way:

```
cd /path/to/workspace/my_app/  # <- directory containing the setup.py
python setup.py install
```

Then, you can use your application's entry point (say "my_entry"):

```
/path/to/virtualenv/dir/bin/my_entry <args>
```

To develop, you create a different virtualenv:

```
cd /path/to/virtualenv/dir/
virtualenv my_app_dev
source my_app_dev/bin/activate

cd /path/to/workspace/my_app/  # <- directory containing the setup.py
pip install -e .
```

You have linked your `my_app_dev` virtualenv to your source code. To check that:

```
pip list
```

**EDIT** More about virtualenvs

You can read the online book [Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) to know more about virtualenvs.